# what is metadata in nestjs framework and when to use method @setmetadata?

Tags: express, nestjs, metadata

I am learning a course topic reflection and metadata from nest documentation. They used `@setmetadata('roles')` but I don't know metadata come from and when they are used?

Answer (score 8):

> I don't know metadata come from

First lets explain what metadata generally means.
Metadata in general means data about data. Its a description of the data in more simpler terms (for e.g data about an image). Taking an example from [here](https://dataedo.com/kb/data-glossary/what-is-metadata).

[image]

> They used `@setmetadata('roles')`.

Nest provides the ability to attach custom data to route handlers through `@SetMetadata`. Its a way to declaratively define and store data about your controller(endpoint).

`@SetMetadata` stores the key value pairs. For example,

```
    SetMetadata('IS_PUBLIC_KEY', true)
    findAll(@Query() paginationQuery: PaginationQueryDto) {
            return this.testService.findAll(paginationQuery);
        }
```

Here I am setting a key `IS_PUBLIC_KEY` with a value set to `true`.

In this scenario you are defining a key named `role` (most probably and it seems it may be missing a value) which will define what certain types or role can access this controller.

> When they are used?

You can use it when you want to define the Guards. For instance, I am using the above `findAll` controller as a public api. In my guard implementation, I check and see if the value of IsPublic is true then allow any consumer to consume the API.

```
  canActivate(
    context: ExecutionContext,
  ): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    const isPublic = this.reflector.get('IS_PUBLIC_KEY', context.getHandler());

    if (isPublic) {
      return true;
    }
}
```

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/execution-context#reflection-and-metadata:

> The `@SetMetadata()` decorator is imported from the `@nestjs/common` package.